# gdb cant execute command while the target in running while remote debugging

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

I am using gdb and gdbserver for debugging my exe. My target is same as local host currently. I start the gdbserver using

`gdbserver.exe :6000 MyTest.exe 1> NUL 2> NUL`

and my gdb is started using

`gdb.exe -ex "set target-async on" -ex "target remote :6000"`

But when I try `info threads` or set or get a global variable , I get cannot execute command target running. I tried to use interrupt before set but this doesn't change anything. Does any one know what could be wrong or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is no input file to the `gdb.exe` in your code. Provide the same `MyTest.exe` file to `gdb` on host so that `gdb` can load the symbols

```
gdb.exe MYTest.exe
(gdb)set target-async on
(gdb)set target remote :6000
```